# SAS HBA card not working

Tags: centos7, sas, lsi, hba

I have a NAS server with three SAS HBA cards. Two are SAS3 and work just fine, they connect to three 48 drive JBOD cabinets. The third is SAS2, connecting to a tape robot with 5 drives, and does not work.

The server is a Supermicro SYS-2029U-TR4T. The SAS2 HBA card in question is an LSI 9201-16e. The server is running CentOS 7 with the latest updates, as of this post.

I have tried moving the card around to different PCIe slots and the best I have been able to do is get it to show up in lspci. In some slots the OS does not even recognize it. When listed in lspci the OS attempts to load the mpt2sas driver which fails with the following output:

```
[ 4401.676636] mpt2sas version 20.103.01.00 loaded
[ 4401.677574] mpt2sas 0000:5e:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[ 4401.677930] mpt2sas_cm0: 64 BIT PCI BUS DMA ADDRESSING SUPPORTED, total mem (791000116 kB)
[ 4401.732434] mpt2sas_cm0: CurrentHostPageSize is 0: Setting default host page size to 4k
[ 4401.732450] mpt2sas_cm0: MSI-X vectors supported: 1
[ 4401.732454] mpt2sas_cm0:  0 1
[ 4401.732548] mpt2sas 0000:5e:00.0: irq 571 for MSI/MSI-X
[ 4401.732637] mpt2sas_cm0: High IOPs queues : disabled
[ 4401.732639] mpt2sas0-msix0: PCI-MSI-X enabled: IRQ 571
[ 4401.732642] mpt2sas_cm0: iomem(0x00000000c5ec0000), mapped(0xffffc243e3960000), size(16384)
[ 4401.732643] mpt2sas_cm0: ioport(0x0000000000009000), size(256)
[ 4401.787430] mpt2sas_cm0: CurrentHostPageSize is 0: Setting default host page size to 4k
[ 4402.306189] mpt2sas_cm0: reply pool: dma_pool_alloc failed
[ 4413.653575] mpt2sas_cm0: failure at drivers/scsi/mpt3sas/mpt3sas_scsih.c:10651/_scsih_probe()!
```

Attempting to list the card with sas2flash, version 20.00.00.00, fails with "No LSI SAS adapters found!"

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you pulled the card and updated its firmware in another computer?

Comment: If other cards work in the slots that this LSI card doesn't, you have a paperweight and not an HBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to flash the card via the UEFI version of sas2flash with a little help from this guide: https://forums.serverbuilds.net/t/guide-updating-your-lsi-sas-controller-with-a-uefi-motherboard/131

The card was using firmware version 13 and once flashed with firmware version 20 it started working fine.